# CPack: Any way to create an installer that should install to a system folder without invoking cpack with root permissions

Tags: macos, plugins, cmake, cpack

I'm trying to create a CPack-based MacOS installer for an audio plugin project. The default location of MacOS audio plugin is in the `/Library/Audio/PlugIns/` folder which needs root rights to be written to.

AFAIK CPack takes the destination path for the installed artifacts from the path specified in the CMake INSTALL command, so my CMakeLists.txt looks like that:

```
# CPack takes these paths as the locations where the plugins should be installed in the end
install (TARGETS MYPLUGIN_VST3 LIBRARY DESTINATION /Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/VST3       COMPONENT VST3)
install (TARGETS MYPLUGIN_AU   LIBRARY DESTINATION /Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/Components COMPONENT AU)

# This makes sure that only the two components and nothing else is part of our installer
SET (CPACK_COMPONENTS_ALL VST3 AU)

# We want to use the native Apple GUI installer
SET (CPACK_GENERATOR productbuild)
```

Now, when I call `cpack` to build the installer it fails because of a permission issue as it installs the plugins as a first step before building the installer. The only solution I found was running `cpack` with root rights to let it write to these locations during the install step which seems like bad practice to me and might be even worse when trying to run this on a build server in future. As I don't need the install step but only want the resulting installer, I wonder if there is any way to avoid the install step and let CPack grab the files to wrap into the installer directly from the binary directory where they were placed after build. Didn't find anything regarding that in the documentations, but I'm just starting with CMake and CPack, so I might overlook something obvious here

Comment: Do not use absolute paths to install files. When CPack assembles the package the very first step is to _pre-install_ files into an image directory and pack it after. Depending on a generator and a platform it's possible to use `DESTDIR`, but that is not your case obviously. So, just use relative install paths in conjunction w/ the `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX`.

Comment: Not sure if I got you wrong, but I tried SET (CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX /Library/) and them removed that bit from the paths above. Now running cpack without root rights works, but the installer generated simply puts the plugins into an Audio/Plug-Ins subfolder it creates in my Applications folder, so that is not what I want. Furthermore the installer also installs headers and binaries from a third party library used in the project to the application although CPACK_COMPONENTS_ALL tells it to do something different (I can see this as Unspecified target in the console output when running cpack).